# Set the default value on a select option drop down

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to make the default value the same as set in the database. This is because i am using it to edit items in the databse and want the values to be preset.

This is currently setting it to black at the start.

```
$_SESSION["menuID"] = $_POST["menuID"];
$menuID = $_POST["menuID"];
$menu_sql = "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menuID = $menuID";
$menu_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $menu_sql);
$menu_aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($menu_query);
$select_sql = "SELECT * FROM course ORDER BY courseID";
$select_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $select_sql);
$select_aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_query);


<select name="courseID">
  <?php do { ?>
  <option selected="<?php echo $select_aa['courseID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $select_aa['courseID']; ?>"><?php echo $select_aa['name']; ?></option>
  <?php } while ($select_aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_query)); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: side note: you're open to an sql injection; use a prepared statement if you value your work and data.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting default using ternary operator.

```
<select name="courseID">
  <?php do { ?>
  <option selected="<?php echo ( $select_aa['courseID'] == 'Your default value here' ? "selected" : "" ); ?>" value="<?php echo $select_aa['courseID']; ?>"><?php echo $select_aa['name']; ?></option>
  <?php } while ($select_aa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_query)); ?>
</select>
```